# Non-Noetherian ring that has an ideal $I$ containing a power of $\sqrt{I}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

We already knew that if $R$ is a Noetherian ring, then every ideal $I$ contains a power of its radical. Now suppose that $R$ is non-Noetherian, is there any example of $R$ such that one of its ideals, denoted by $I$, contains a power of $\sqrt{I}$, and the power is greater than or equal to $2$?

To make it easier, we can discuss with the ring $R=C^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, which is the ring of continuous map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This ring is not Noetherian and I knew some of its maximal ideals. Is there any ideal $I$ such that $(\sqrt{I})^n=I$ for some $n \geq 2$?

Great to discuss with everyone for this.

Comment: I=0 and R reduced. The question is trivial. What do you really want to know?

Comment: Is there any non-trivial example?

Comment: Take $R=k\left[x_1, x_2, \ldots\right]$ the polynomial ring of countable indeterminants and $I=\left( x_1^n\right)$. Then $\sqrt{I}=\left(x_1\right)$ and $(\sqrt{I})^n=I$. I think the ring of all continuous functions over the real line is harder to construct an example or to prove it doesn’t exist.